# The `rm` command in my SystemD unit file keeps failing

Tags: systemd

I have the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nethogs Daemon
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple 
ExecStart=/sbin/nethogs -t -d 1 -v3 -s
StandardOutput=file:/tmp/nethogs.stdout
StandardError=file:/tmp/nethogs.stderr
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.*

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `rm` command keeps failing, no matter how I use it:

```
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.*
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.{stdout,stderr}
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.stdout && /bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.stderr
```

I get the following error message when I run `systemctl status nethogs.service`:

```
Process: 26801 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.* (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Can someone give me a hint please how to get this done properly in order to remove the two files mentioned under `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`?

Comment: Why not put the rm command into a shell script & call it instead. Then add debugging statements to it so you can see what is happening.

Comment: You can't use wildcards directly in a systemd unit. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162993/how-to-use-wildcards-in-systemd-services

Comment: There is no native support for shell wildcards, shell brace expansion etc. But you can have multiple command lines with [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=)  and should be able to do `ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.stdout` and a next line with `ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs.stderr`

Comment: @HBruijn yes indeed, though associated with strange behaviour: Now I have two `ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /tmp/nethogs...` statements and one file gets deleted but the other just shrunk to a size of 0 bytes which leaves me pondering why this is so.